# Histogram Comparison Using Pyramid Match Kernel Distance

Tags: matlab, image-processing, chi-squared

I am following spatial pyramid representation for images (both Sketch and Photo), i.e. dividing image into `2L` levels and each level `l = 0, 1, ..., L-1` has `22l` grids.

It means `level 0` has `1` grid (single image), `level 1` has `4` grids and so on.

I have considered the `4 levels` here. I am dividing image up to `4 levels` i.e. `64 blocks`. Then divided image at each level has that many numbers of histograms (e.g. `level 1` has `4 blocks` so `4 histograms` and so on) then obtained final histogram by merging these histograms (keeping this example final histogram is obtained by merging 4 histograms and so on).

Then this final histogram of sketch image is matched with the final histogram of photo image at each level.

I want to compare the histograms of two images i.e. sketch image histogram (input from user) and photo image (database of colour image though I haven’t created database yet but I need to create. Please also help me with that as well) using Pyramid Match Kernel (PMK) Distance. This distance is given as below: I want Source code for implenting this distance.

```
d(Hp, L, Hs, L) = chi-Square(Hp, 0, Hs, 0) / 2L + l = 1L ∑chi-Square(Hp, l, Hs, l) / 2L - l -1
```

where:

- L - number of levels = 4 (That is I am considering)
- l - individual levels, i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3 (Since I am considering 4 levels)
- Hs - Sketch Histogram
- Hp - Photo Histogram

Currently I am statically computing these histograms but I need to store four histograms for one photo image in `.mat` database of matlab (four histograms since first for level one, second for level two, third for level three and fourth for level four), so that I can run loop for comparing the input image histogram with the histograms of images in database.

I need your help for both implementing this PMK distance and creating database to store 4 histograms for single photo image. Currently I have 100 images with me so I need to store histograms corresponding to each photo image in `.mat` file, tell me how do I do that?

Comment: In the distance above there is two Race to power is there. i.e. 2^L and 2^2l but it is not showing in the question. In summation sign it is from L=1 to l(here l=4). i.e. 0,1,2,3 But 0 is considered in first term of distance equation and rest summation have three remaining levels. The summation term has denominator as 2^(L-l-1).

Comment: Chi_square Distance is used above which is given as built-in function in mat lab.